# Angular ui-router - dont reload templates for same view URL

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

I am using the ui-router to manage a deeply nested routing setup which is composed of multiple frames within a page.

Something like this:

```
<html>
<body>
    <div ui-view="foo"></div>
    <div ui-view="bar"></div>
    <div ui-view="baz"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

My routing file is something like this:

```
app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state('alpha', {
            url: '/alpha',
            views: {
                'foo': {templateUrl: '/partials/foo.html'},
                'bar': {templateUrl: '/partials/bar.html'},
                'baz': {templateUrl: '/partials/baz.html'},
            },
        })
        .state('beta', {
            url: '/beta',
            views: {
                'foo': {templateUrl: '/partials/foo.html'},
                'bar': {templateUrl: '/partials/quz.html'},
                'baz': {templateUrl: '/partials/qux.html'},
            },
        })
        .state('gamma', {
            url: '/gamma',
            views: {
                'foo': {templateUrl: '/partials/flarp.html'},
                'bar': {templateUrl: '/partials/corge.html'},
                'baz': {templateUrl: '/partials/qux.html'},
            },
        })
});
```

The page is made up of multiple panels and this setup is working fine. However each URL change forces all ui-views elements to reload - even if the URL is the same.

For example moving from `/alpha` to `/beta` will reload the `<div ui-view="foo"></div>` element even though the view URL is the same.

Does anyone have any idea on how I can stop the views reloading if the view URL is the same as previous?

Comment: I think that's just the way it works, since you change states. If you don't want it to reload a particular view, consider putting that view in a parent abstract state.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid that as the nesting of the routes doesn't really allow this approch